# Regex to match function return types in vim

Tags: c++, regex, vim

I'm using c++ with a header file that is quite large and would like to do a search for functions with specific return types, such as int. The problem lies in the fact that there is white space in front of the return types as shown below.

```
    Set<Animal*> _animals;

    int _getMonkeyCount(Zoo* zoo);

    bool _addUnicorn(Animal* unicorn, int age = EXTINCT );

    string _toString(Zoo* z);

    void _addMonkeyz(Animal* monkey, List<string> fleaNames);
```

I would like to have a regex that matches one of the return types. For example bool, but I do not want to match the space in front of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want something like:

```
/^\s\+\zsbool
```

The key here is `\zs` which defines the start of the match.  There is also `\ze` to define the end of the match but you don't need that here.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
^\s\+int
^\s\+bool
```

etc.

Comment: That matches the spaces in front, I was already able to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
'^ *int '
```

Remove the quotes when you run it.  Of course, this highlights a few extra characters too...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but this might help someone else (matches function definitions, probably can be improved).

This Perl regex supports:

- pointers
- names
- function arguments
- the static qualifier
- the const qualifier (in both locations)
- constructor parameters

`/((?:static\s+)?(?:const\s+)?(?:\w+\s+)(?:\*\s+)?(?:const(:?\s*))?)([\w|~]+)(\(.*\))(.*)\{/`

Issues:

- no preprocessor support (e.g. dllexport, etc.)
- extra match group seems to have snuck in